# PHP and Apache customization on Bitnami+Redmine Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, redmine, bitnami

**What I am trying to do:**

- Use Redmine pre-setup on the instance, for project management.
- Host my website (PHP) and tweak Apache.
- Install Wordpress on Bitnami+Redmine Amazon EC2 instance.

**Problem:**

- Customization of Bitnami+Redmine Amazon EC2 instance.

I am using `bitnami-redmine-1.2.1-0-linux-ubuntu-10.04-ebs` (ami-47e82c2e).

I'v had troubles modifying `php.ini` and `httpd.conf` for Web Hosting customizations.

Is this possible ?

Tried modifying `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`
and then a reboot without any fruit.

Also, tried modifying `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` without success.

Anyone who tried similar tweaks successfully ?
Is there any other free/pay Bitnami+Redmine Amazon EC2 instance that I could use/buy and also customize ?

Comment: "Customization of Bitnami" That Bitnami is preconfigured for Redmine. Are you talking about the virtual appliance version? I guess you are better off installing Redmine on a fresh install. Its pretty straightforward.

Comment: @aitchnyu, Yes, I took the Amazon EC2 image pre-configured with Ubuntu + Redmine. Later I decided to host website from within, and that's when I ran into troubles. May be I should take a plain Ubuntu instance and then add Redmine, Wordpress and tweak around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitNami offers the [BitNami Cloud Hosting](http://bitnami.org/cloud) service that allows you to easily run Redmine and WordPress (and other applications) on top of the same server. The base image already includes ruby and php and you just need to select which applications you need to install on top of it. There is free developer plan and other paid plans offers.

Also the latest [BitNami Redmine AMI](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine#cloudImage) already includes php configured with Apache so you may want to give it a try. Notice that php will be installed in /opt/bitnami/php.